# Gradle does not generate Javadocs

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc

I am writing a build file with Gradle to do Java build operations. However, Gradle does not generate Javadocs for my project. According to Gradle.org's documentation, to implement a Javadocs task in Gradle, the source and classpath have to be specified.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

javadoc {
source = sourceSets.main.allJava
classpath = configurations.compile
}
```

However, when I run the command `gradle javadoc`, or `gradle build`, the default folder for javadocs (build\docs) is never created, so no html files are generated for the project. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to reconfigure the `javadoc` task like this; the defaults will do. `gradle build` won't run `javadoc`, but `gradle javadoc` will. If that doesn't work, something fundamental might be wrong with your build. Are you sure you are looking at the right `build` directory? Is the task shown as `skipped` or `up-to-date`? What does the `--info` log say? Which Gradle version?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I ran it with the `--info` flag, and I got a message that says `Skipping task ':javadoc' as it has no source files.`. I don't know why it is skipping the task because I have specified the `source` property as `sourceSets.main.allJava`

Comment: As I said, you don't have to set that property. Perhaps your source files are in the wrong directory, or you are running the task on the wrong project.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to define the source directory in the Main sourceSet. Once I did that, it ran perfectly.

Comment: I am in the same situation, how do you define the sources? I think there is something wrong with my project setup (Intellij IDEA).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your directory structure is is not a standard `src/main/java`. If that is the case then you need to specify the include pattern as part of the [include](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc:include(groovy.lang.Closure)) closure, something like this:

```
javadoc {
source = sourceSets.main.allJava
classpath = configurations.compile
}
include **/your/directory/structure/*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a gradle task of type Javadoc to create javadocs like this :

```
 task createJavadocs (type: Javadoc)
      {
            source = project.android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
            options.linkSource true
            classpath += project.files(project.android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
            failOnError false
      }
```

To create Javadocs, simply run this task.

Answer (score 0):

For various reasons we created a custom classpath in gradle for our java project. Mainly as we wanted to split out dependancies into those provided at runtime from those that weren't.

So we set up build.gradle like this

```
configurations {
  providedCompile
}

dependencies {

  providedCompile  'provided1', 'provided2

  providedCompile  'provided3'

  compile 'compile1'
  compile ('compile2')   
  { 
        exclude group: 'unwanted part'
  }

}
sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += configurations.providedCompile
javadoc.classpath += configurations.providedCompile
sourceSets.test.compileClasspath += configurations.providedCompile
sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.providedCompile
```

We needed to add the final part in order for gradle to correctly pick up the classpath for complying, testing AND running javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

If **include** closure is not working the add **sourceSet** closure with **srcDir** pointing to the module/java directory.

The below example is properly working for me. Here java directory is src/main/java
, where I have all my packages.

```
sourceSets {
    build {
        java.srcDir file('src/integrationTest/java')
    }
}

javadoc {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    classpath = configurations.compile
}
```

The run $*gradle javadoc*

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little more structure to the answers, these are the configs needed to generate Javadoc (using **Gradle version 4 and 5**).

**1. Define your sourceSet** (might be optional if the standard Maven directory structure is used). Assuming this directory structure:

```
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
├── src
│   └── test
│       ├── java
```

Define sourceSet like this

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
               srcDirs =['src/main/java']
    }
    test {
        java {
               srcDirs =['src/test/java']
    }
}
```

**2. Configure classpath** to be used when generating javadoc. If this is not done, it will result in errors similar to this: `error: package org.xxxx` does not exist.

Assuming your dependency is defined like this:

```
dependency {
   compile group: 'xxxx', name: 'yyyy', version: 'zzzz'
   testCompile group: 'aaaa', name: 'bbbb', version: 'cccc'
}
```

define javadoc task this way

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc){
source = sourceSet.main.java.srcDirs
classpath +=configuration.compile
destinationDir = reporting.file("myJavaDoc") //optional
}
```

If you want to generate Java doc for test, the task will look like this:

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc){
source = sourceSet.test.java.srcDirs
classpath +=configuration.compile
classpath +=configuration.testCompile
destinationDir = reporting.file("myJavaDoc") //optional
}
```